# Next.js <Image/> in component at page directory

Tags: next.js

Why I have to import static image path differently for component in Page directory?

Page>Product

```
import soldImg from '../../assets/images/soldbig.png';

<Image src={soldImg} width={300} height={300} />
```

was not working..but

```
import soldImg from '../../assets/images/soldbig.png';
<Image src={`..${soldImg.src}`} width={300} height={300} />
```

if I change the path (soldImg automatically had 'product' at path) like this, Image tag show image correctly..

Why We have to do this for dynamic route component? Also Is there better way to show the Image correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to handle static content on nextJs is using the `public` folder, so create a folder called `public` at the root directory of your project. Supposing that your public folder structure looks like this: `public/assets/images/soldbig.png`, you could access the image like so:

```
<Image src={'/assets/images/soldbig.png'} width={300} height={300} />
```

Now the import is optional because nextJs looks for the public folder and loads the image automatically, to know more about it, please, [read the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving).

Comment: While you could do it that way, the way OP is trying to do is also valid. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#local-images.

Comment: yeah, i already known about the import, maybe i didn't express myself very well, anyway, thanks for the advice!